# postgresql: time zone "localtime" not recognized

Tags: c, postgresql

I've tried querying `select now() at time zone 'localtime';` on both Mac and Windows and it results to **ERROR:  time zone "localtime" not recognized** but somehow it works properly on Linux.

Any idea how to make it work on both Mac and Windows?

I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030175/postgres-at-time-zone-localtime-at-time-zone-utc) that doing this query uses a C library which I suppose has a similar structure to the one described [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_localtime.htm). I've compiled and ran it on a Mac (via gcc) and it works but the postgresql query won't.

Answer (score 2):

Time zone names are matched against the `name` column in the view [pg_timezone_names](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-timezone-names.html).

If you have no `localtime` in there and you don't want to hardcode a time zone, you could do

```
select now()::timestamp;
```

which I think is just the same than what you'd expect from `select now() at time zone 'localtime'`